# TClientDataSet Tabela Temporária

Tags: delphi, xml, tabela-html, tclientdataset

Boa noite.

Minha dúvida é a seguinte, estou com uma tabela temporária criada no `TClientDataSet`.

Porém, eu preciso gravar os dados da tabela temporária em um arquivo XML e depois ler novamente no `TClientDataSet`, ou seja, deletar os registros e reinserir todos eles.

Porém, no meu `ListView`, está aparecendo registros duplicados ou registros vazios, e já verifiquei o XML, e está tudo ok.

Alguma dica sobre Tabelas temporárias usando o `TClientDataSet`?

Comment: O XML você criou na mão ou foi salvo pelo CDS ? Posta seu XML para eu dar uma olhada!

Comment: Foi na mão mesmo, ele não serviria muito pra mim criado pelo CDS, Vou postar a resposta escrita.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então, depois de muita pesquisa, soube que o `ApplyUpdates(0);` não funciona em tabelas temporárias, ou seja, tudo que fiz foi definir os campos que quero no `TClientDataSet` após isto, botão direito e `CreateDataSet`, então para concluir, faça suas alterações desta maneira:

Editar:

```
cds.Edit;
valor := cdscampo.value;
cds.Post;
```

Adicionar:

```
cds.Append;
cdscampo.value := valor;
cds.Post;
```

Deletar:

```
cds.Delete;
```

Para simplificar, utilizei o IXMLDocument declarado e criado na própria função de gravação.